# Comic book about ninjas with liquid masks

Tags: story-identification, comics

It's been quite a while since I read this so everything is very hazy.

This comic must have been from late eighties/early nineties.
There were ninjas involved and they had masks that appeared to slide on and off their faces like liquid.
I believe some (all?) also had fedoras (or similar type of hat) for their outfit.
Finally, I think they were in Hell, riding a double-decker bus and fighting the baddies.

Please tell me I haven't made all this up :)

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: I don't remember fedoras, but I can tell you that the rest sounds vaguely familiar.

Comment: Fedoras seem very impractical for ninjas.

Comment: @phantom42 fedoras are cool now.